# Are there example layouts to make doxygen documentation more appealing?

Tags: layout, doxygen

I was really amazed how the doxygen documentation can look like, for example [KDE](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kdeclarative/html/index.html).

I would love to use a similar style for my own packages. Can anybody tell me how to configure doxygen to make my documentation look better? I assume that this can all be done using [this](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) but I wonder if there are some example stylesheets and layout xml files are available anywhere. I did not find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen lets you customize the layout using different tags. You need to specify them in your Doxyfile before compiling the documentation. Take a look [here](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/customize.html) for the official doxygen manual on custom output.

If you don't feel like doing all the work yourself, there are some options for doxygen stylesheets online. Just have a quick google.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second link is scam

Comment: @duddel, thanks for pointing that out! I swear it was a legitimate link when I added it... I've now removed it.